# Applying for B1/B2 while under the ESTA visa in USA

Tags: visas, usa, esta, b1-b2-visas

I am a Maltese citizen, and I am visiting the USA currently by ESTA visa (visa waiver program), so I can't stay here more than three months, but I need to stay more because I have to spend more time with my uncle, whose wife passed away. I need to know if I can apply for a B1/B2 visa while in USA or from any other country near USA that allows me to stay more.

Comment: Personal opinion here, so not an attempt at an answer. I would expect you to have issues getting a visa (B2) to come back in, even to support your family. Actually, especially because you are supporting your family. I would expect a consular official to question your willingness to leave, *because* of that.

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible to apply for a B2 visa whilst in the US - it must be done at a US Consulate outside of the US.

There is a process for extending a VWP stay by up to 30 days in the event of an "emergency". The process is described on the [CBP website](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1024/~/how-to-extend-my-visa-waiver-program-stay-in-the-u.s.-if-there-is-an-emergency), and will involve contacting the nearest USCIS Field Office, which can be found on [the USCIS website](http://www.uscis.gov/about-us/find-uscis-office).

Depending on the exact situation it's very possible that this would not constitute an "emergency", but contacting the USCIS to request an extension doesn't have a downside so it's worth at least trying.